# how to pass folder that contains whitesapce to RCTP to

Tags: smtp, lmtp

I used LMTP command like RCTP to: "uid+folder@domain".

The deliver is succeeded when I use the folder name without any whitespace inside.

```
RCTP to:<test+test@test.com">
```

But I get "500 5.5.2 Syntax error in recipient address" when I use the folder(test test) contains whitespace.

```
RCTP to:<test+test test@test.com">
```

Please help.

Comment: Not familiar with LMTP but SMTP requires quoting around whitespace. Try `<"test+test test"@test.com>`

Comment: Doesn't work. RCPT TO:<"test+test test"@test.com>
450 4.2.1 Mailbox disabled, not accepting messages
503 5.5.1 No recipients

Comment: Probably a question for the maintainer of the server you are using. We can tell you what the protocol says but not how it maps to a local resource without knowing which piece of software is doing the mapping. Either way, this should be migrated to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Can you post names of both communicating servers? [e.g. postfix to dovecot]